# mysqldump on mariadb 10.2.44 CentOS 7 does not work, but mysql does

Tags: centos, mariadb

CentOS 7 MariaDB 10.2.44.

```
X [root@psa95 ~]$ rpm -qa | grep Maria
MariaDB-server-10.2.44-1.el7.centos.x86_64
MariaDB-common-10.2.44-1.el7.centos.x86_64
MariaDB-compat-10.2.44-1.el7.centos.x86_64
MariaDB-client-10.2.44-1.el7.centos.x86_64
✓ [root@psa95 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
```

Credentials supplied in /root/.my.cnf with sections for client, mysqldump, mysql.

```
X [root@psa95 ~]$ mysql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 4875
Server version: 10.2.44-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> Bye
✓ [root@psa95 ~]$ mysqldump mysql
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect
```

The mysql command works.  The mysqldump command doesn't.

I have tried using -p to prompt for the password, and supplying username and password on the commandline.  Same thing -- works with mysql, does not work with mysqldump.

Another CentOS 7 system with exactly the same MariaDB version and the same setup in .my.cnf works perfectly.  I have compared the mysqldump binary from both systems, they are identical.

I've scoured Google and tried every single idea I could find.  None of it worked.  What else can I try?  What other information is needed to troubleshoot?  I know the password is good -- it works with the mysql command.

Comment: "mysqldump dump" dumps the database "mysql".  Is there any issue dumping _your_ database?

Comment: I can't dump ANY of the databases.  I've tried them all.  If I can get the auth to work, it will be root@localhost, which has no limitations.  There must be some difference between the system that works and the one that doesn't that I haven't found yet which is critical for mysqldump to work.  I can't make auth work with /root/.my.cnf or supplying credentials on the commandline.  The mysql client command works perfectly, mysqldump doesn't.

We have a sync script.  An early step dumps databases on the source (excluding test and the *_schema databases) and imports them on the target system.

Comment: When putting auth into `my.cnf`, be sure to put in the correct "sections", such as `[mysqld[`, `[mysqldump]`, `[client]`, etc..

Comment: I had the same credentials in three sections:  [mysql] , [mysqldump] , and [client].  Works perfectly on another system, but for this one and two others just like it, it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that mysqldump needed --ssl to function properly.